# How to access method return from if statement in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, methods, return

I have a method that returns an array, like this:

```
def foobar(foo, bar)
  if foo != bar
    [foo, bar]
  end
end
```

Now, I want to call this method from inside my code using an if statement. How do I access the array values without having to duplicate the method?

```
if foobar("baz", "qux")
    foo = foobar("baz", "qux")
    puts foo[0], foo[1]
end
```

For further clarification, I mean something along the lines of `$~` when you call a regex match in an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has a concept called "local variables". You can assign objects to variables and then reference those variables:

```
if foo = foobar('baz', 'qux')
  puts foo[0], foo[1]
end
```

Note that [`Kernel#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) special-cases [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) arguments and prints their elements on new lines, so your code is equivalent to the more idiomatic

```
if foo = foobar('baz', 'qux')
  puts foo
end
```

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I needed, but couldn't figure out. Thanks! I realise the second part as well, but that really wasn't my focus here, as my actual code differs from this simplified version by a long shot.

Comment: @MattSchuchard: What exactly should I test equality against? There are no equality tests in the OP's code.